# Get particular value from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How to get a particular key from dictionary in python?

I have a dictionary as :

```
dict = {'redorange':'1', 'blackhawak':'2', 'garlicbread':'3'}
```

I want to get value of that key which contains garlic in its key name.
How I can achieve it?

Comment: Never name your dict "`dict`"; this shadows the builtin `dict`, which is the dictionary type, which you may need to call at some point.

Comment: ok thanks for the information. it will help me in future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's call your dictionary `d`:

```
print [v for k,v in d.iteritems() if 'garlic' in k]
```

prints a list of all corresponding values:

```
['3']
```

If you know you want a single value:

```
print next(v for k,v in d.iteritems() if 'garlic' in k)
```

prints

```
'3'
```

This raises `StopIterationError` if no such key/value is found. Add the default value:

```
print next((v for k,v in d.iteritems() if 'garlic' in k), None)
```

to get `None` if such a key is not found (or use another default value).