# Getting dictionary value from within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using google geocache to obtain the latitude and longitude from an address. It outputs the following

```
  {'address_components': [{'long_name': '101', 'short_name': '101', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Oak Street', 'short_name': 'Oak St', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Hayes Valley', 'short_name': 'Hayes Valley', 'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'San Francisco', 'short_name': 'SF', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'San Francisco County', 'short_name': 'San Francisco County', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '94102', 'short_name': '94102', 'types': ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '101 Oak St, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA', 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.77513769999999, 'lng': -122.4210453}, 'southwest': {'lat': 37.7750128, 'lng': -122.4211758}}, 'location': {'lat': 37.7750683, 'lng': -122.4210876}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.7764242302915, 'lng': -122.4197615697085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 37.7737262697085, 'lng': -122.4224595302915}}}, 'partial_match': True, 'place_id': 'ChIJZQRo4J6AhYARbQ70tvpMUfE', 'types': ['subpremise']}
```

If we assume that this is stored in a variable, how would I obtain both the latitude and longitude using python?

I'm looking to get the following longitude and latitude from this and store each in a variable:

```
location': {'lat': 37.7750683, 'lng': -122.4210876}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Getting an element of a list, and getting a value out of a dict, are introductory items you can find in any tutorial on each data type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get particular value from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830128/get-particular-value-from-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `d` be the dictionary you posted, then

```py
loc = d["geometry"]["location"]
lat, lng = loc["lat"], loc["lng"]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
your_provided_dict = {'address_components': [{'long_name': '101', 
'short_name': '101', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Oak Street', 
'short_name': 'Oak St', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Hayes Valley', 
'short_name': 'Hayes Valley', 'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': 'San Francisco', 'short_name': 'SF', 'types': ['locality', 
'political']}, {'long_name': 'San Francisco County', 'short_name': 'San 
Francisco County', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, 
{'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA', 'types': 
['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 
'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '94102', 
'short_name': '94102', 'types': ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '101 
Oak St, San Francisco, CA 94102, USA', 'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': 
{'lat': 37.77513769999999, 'lng': -122.4210453}, 'southwest': {'lat': 
37.7750128, 'lng': -122.4211758}}, 'location': {'lat': 37.7750683, 'lng': 
-122.4210876}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 
37.7764242302915, 'lng': -122.4197615697085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 
37.7737262697085, 'lng': -122.4224595302915}}}, 'partial_match': True, 
'place_id': 'ChIJZQRo4J6AhYARbQ70tvpMUfE', 'types': ['subpremise']}

your_provided_dict_bounds = test_d['geometry']['bounds']
location_list = []
for key,value in your_provided_dict_bounds.items():
    location = "location:"+str(value)
    location_list.append(location)
    print(location_list)
```

The above code provides the output that you have wanted as per your question. At last, i have appended all the locations into a list. Please take a look at the code by me.